# Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar', and try again

Tags: macos, hadoop, apache-pig

I downloaded pig 0.14.0 and I am running Hadoop 2.6.0 on MAC OSX. I followed all the installation steps for PIG at https://github.com/ucbtwitter/getting-started/wiki/Installing-Pig .I had set JAVA_HOME correctly as mentioned.

Even after running the ant "-Dhadoopversion=23 jar" command I am getting the same error "Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar', and try again".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error constantly arising

Cannot locate pig-core-h2.jar. do 'ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar', and try again.

I studied the shell script by opening pig-0.14.0/bin/pig file and found that this error is related to the setting of CLASSPATH and PIG_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables.

Then I found that I mispelled the PIG_HOME then I corrected it.

Next I ran that specified command('ant -Dhadoopversion=23 jar') in the pig installation directory.

Then I got this error 
Not a valid JAR: /Users/../../../pig-0.14.0/pig-0.14.0-SNAPSHOT-core-h2.jar /Users/../../../pig-0.14.0/pig-0.14.0-core-h2.jar

To resolve it remove that jar file in that location.

Then I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Find the path to the file `pig-*-core-h2.jar`.

I installed pig using `brew install pig` and found the jar in the path `/usr/local/Cellar/pig/0.17.0/libexec`

Run `export PIG_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/pig/0.17.0/libexec`

This will fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

i did this to fix the pig

mv /data/mapr/pig/pig-0.14/pig-0.14.0-mapr-1603-core-h2.jar /data/mapr/pig/pig-0.14/pig-0.14.0-mapr-1603-core-h2.jar.orig

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions works:
Please make sure in your .bash_profile or .bashrc you have following environment variables:

export PIG_HOME="/Library/apache-pig-0.15.0"

export PATH="/Library/apache-pig-0.15.0/bin:${PATH}"

restart the machine or restart the unix terminal;

I replaced  /Library/apache-pig-0.15.0/ with  "home/cwu/Downloads/pig-0.15.0-src
"